# Deleting a word in a string from a file, Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm scanning a the text of a C file and searching for any comments in the file, comments being in the form..

`/* this is a comment */`

My regex expression to find comments is

```
comment = r'\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^/])*\*\/'
```

Then I do this to scan the file and to find comments...

```
for line in pstream:
            findComment = re.search(comment, line)
            if findComment:
                Comment = findComment.group(0)
                if isinstance(Comment, str):
                    print(Comment)
                if isinstance(line, str):
                    print(line)
                line = re.sub(Comment, "", line)
                print(line)
```

I want to find the comments and delete them from the text of the file..

But my output for the above code is..

```
/* hello */
#include  /* hello */ "AnotherFile.h"
#include  /* hello */ "AnotherFile.h"
```

On the second print of `line` I want `/* hello */` to not be there, which I would assume would mean that the comment was deleted from file.. But my `re.sub` doesn't seem to do anything to it..

Any help?

EDIT:
I'm not sure why the two `#include` prints are in a lighter shade, but to clarify, they are also printed just like `/* hello */` is

I tested my `re.sub` in another file with the code

```
import re

line = '#include /* hello */ "file.h"'
Comment = '/* hello */'

line = re.sub(Comment, " ", line)

print(line)
```

And it prints..

```
#include /* hello */ "file.h"
```

But I don't want the `/* hello */` to be there :(

Comment: what in earth is `if isinstance(Comment, str)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: I was trying to figure out what was wrong, so I put it there to check if `line` and `Comment` are actually strings...

Comment: They could not really be anything else

Comment: yea I figured, oh well its not a big deal

Comment: yea, I tested it on http://regexr.com
Also, i assume it is correct since the print statement, `print(Comment)` is the comment found in the text of the C file.
`re.sub(r"\/\*.*?\*\/","",s)` is giving an error

Comment: If it finds them then re.sub  should be removing the substrings. What does it output if you test it on a single line? This sub removes every comment from your input `re.sub(r"/\*.*?\*/","",s)`

Comment: You are not expecting the  lines to be removed from the file?

Comment: "I want to find the comments and delete them from the text of the file.."

I won't want the line to be removed, just the comment within the line

Comment: You are not passing a regex, you are passing a string -> Comment = '/* hello */'

Comment: ohhhhh!! After reading that, I simply replaced the `Comment` in my `re.sub` with `r'\/\*(?:[^*]|\*[^/])*\*\/'` , my regex expression to find comments, and tada it worked! Thank you!

Comment: No worries, unrelated but you don't need to escape the `/`

Comment: oh no..
unfortunately it doesn't actually delete the comment in the C file itself.. hmm.. I know this because after the `for line in pstream:` in my posted question is done, I make separate `for line in stream:` with a `print(line)` in it, that is after the first one, and sure enough, the comment shows up in the line..

Comment: you realise that you actually have to overwrite the content in the file to see the changes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30033161/python3-4-how-to-delete-a-section-of-text-following-pattern-string-match/30033342#30033342 Just use  `for line in f:out.write(re.sub(r"/\*.*?\*/","",line))` replacing `"test.txt"` with your file name

Answer (score 0):

I see you are using the `Comment` as a regex. Since it may (and *does* in this case) contain special regex metacharacters, you need to [**re.escape**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) them.

Use `re.escape(Comment)`:

```
line = re.sub(re.escape(Comment), "", line)
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/aPBnf1)

The output of the second `print` is now as expected:

```
/* hello */
#include  /* hello */ "AnotherFile.h"
#include   "AnotherFile.h"
```

To make sure the initial spaces are removed, you can append `r"\s*"` in the beginning ([see demo](http://ideone.com/qERWEG)):

```
line = re.sub(r"\s*" + re.escape(Comment), "", line)
```